# MVC vs Single Page Apps - When is MVC more appropriate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, prototype

When is it better to have multiple views in something like MVC, as opposed to a single view via something like Prototype calling a Web API?  It seems like in terms of UX, the single-page app with AJAX calls will always be better.

Comment: MVC and SPA are not mutually exclusive

Comment: I think you can still apply MVC pattern to single page apps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/19/mvc-single-page-template-update-for-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC is an architecture approach that separates the view from the model and connects the two via a controller. It is used to separate concerns that may have different audience and life-cycles. It applies to Web applications and other types of user-interface applications as well such as desktop, thick client and rich client apps.

As the comment says, a single page with a Java applet, Flash movie or Javascript/AJAX is not mutually exclusive with MVC.  Your view is in the page, the model will most likely be on the server if you are using AJAX, although it may be within Javascript if the AJAX is purely for persistence to a 'dumb' data store.

So, you can have full MVC within a Javascript application and most frameworks are designed that way.  Maybe your question was a comparison between web page to server controllers as compared to controllers in Javascript within the page?